# ie7 z-index strange behaviour

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have a problem with ie7 **z-index** behaviour.

Opening [this page](http://www.aralimentare.com/) with ie7, the dropdown menu (some sections have it, some other doesn't) falls behind the slider.

I tried to solve using z-index and position of the parent element, but couldn't fix the thing.

Do you have any idea how to make the dropdown menu stay in front of the slider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the nav menu with an additional container, then give to the wrapping div a bigger z-index than the z-index used in the nav menu.

This is a known issue of IE7 reported [HERE](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html) on 2006.

There's an article that shows the workaround that can be used to solve the problem.
Take a look [HERE](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/).

As an example imagine you have a `div` with `id="menu"` for your navigation menu, you should do something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; z-index: 1000;">
    <div id="menu" style="position:absolute; z-index: 999;"></div>
</div>
```

I think you can easily adapt it to your website.
Now i don't have a copy of IE7 and i can't reproduce the problem, but you can try and that should fix your problem. If it doesn't i'll try to assist you furtherly.

Comment: I had a similar issue last year, and the problem was fixed by setting the overflow of the 'wrapper' div to visible.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of all this (wrapping and incremental z-index for all parent elements) but I couldn't figure out a way of fixing it. Any specific advice would much-more-than-well appreciated.